# How to programmatically focus on a menu button of an editor view in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am working on a vscode extension. I have some custom menu button added to the active editor view. I have a webview to show custom content in the active editor window. I would like to set the focus back to some menu button of the current active editor view when user clicks on something inside the webview.
For example,

[image: custom menu button in active editor view]

Is there a way to do that?

I searched through VS Code documentation, and I don't see there is any command to do so. I only see the command to focus on a view, but not the menu buttons in that view.

Answer (score 0):

You have no control of these elements. Even with DOM access in a webview there's no way to access elements outside of this webview.